# Keeping unknown items count in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I am parsing a data source and want to populate an object in JS to end up somehting like this:

```
data = {
    "USA":
        {"NY":{"active":5,"inactive":2}},
        {"WA":{"active":16,"inactive":11}},
    "Canada":
        {"NY":{"active":5,"inactive":2}}
}
```

In the beginning I do not know the number of countries or states I will get data for. So I start like this:

```
var data = {}
```

Then try to populate data like this:

```
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] = data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]++;
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create object properties that way on the fly. So you are creating correctly the data object:

```
var data = {}
```

but the next line is wrong because:

`data["USA"]` is undefined at that moment, so you can't access `["NY"]` of `undefined`, that will throw an exception. So you not only need to initialize the root `data` object, you also need to initialize an object for each property of that object.

You can do it literally:

```
if(!data["USA"]) 
    data["USA"] = {};
```

or using the `||` operator, which will assign to `data["USA"]` the same object if it exists (so it will basically nothing do), or it will create a new one:

```
data["USA"] = data["USA"] || {};
```

now you need to perform this logic for each object which you wan't access. So using the shorter syntax:

```
data["USA"] = data["USA"] || {};
data["USA"]["NY"] = data["USA"]["NY"] || {};
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] = data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] || 0;
```

After that, your object structure is ready, just keep in mind that `++` is an operator that returns the number, and after that adds one to that number.

So:

```
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] = data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]++;
```

will not change the number, you have to do either:

```
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]++;
```

or:

```
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] = data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]+1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need for every level of the object a check and if not set, then take either an object as default or for number, zero.

```js
var data = {};

data["USA"] = data["USA"] || {};
data["USA"]["NY"] = data["USA"]["NY"] || {};
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] = data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] || 0;
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]++;

console.log(data);
```

A better approach is to use a function for checking and making a default object

```js
function getValue(o, path) {
    return path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, o);
}

function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.slice(),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r[a] = r[a] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

function increment(object, path, value) {
    setValue(data, path, (getValue(data, path) || 0 ) + (value || 1));
}

var data = {};
increment(data, ['USA', 'NY', 'active'], 1);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> data["USA"]["NY"]["active"] = data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]++;
> ```

You are:

1. taking the value of `data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]` (which is 2)
2. incrementing `data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]` (so it is now 3)
3. assigning the value you took (2) to `data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]` (effectively reversing the effect of the previous step)

If you want to increment the value then do this:

```
data["USA"]["NY"]["active"]++;
```

… just that, and nothing but that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function using `reduce()` that can take string as nested object keys and build that deep object structure.

```js
var data = {}

function add(str) {
  var arr = str.split('.')
  return arr.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    return arr.length - 1 != i ? r[e] || (r[e] = {}) : r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1
  }, data)
}

add('USA.NY.active')
add('USA.NY.active')
add('USA.NY.inactive')
add('Canada.NY.active')
console.log(data)
```